# How can I have a Modify/Change install run the XmlConfig action to accept new values (values from public properties)?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have XmlConfig entries such as this:

```
<util:XmlConfig Id='SetSomething'
                File="[WEBSITE]Web.config"
                Action='create'
                Node='value'
                ElementPath="//configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='something'[\]]/@value"
                Value="[SOMETHING]"
                On='install'
                PreserveModifiedDate='no'
                VerifyPath="//configuration/appSettings/add[\[]@key='something'[\]]/@value"
               />
```

Which works fine on Install. However for Modify/Change installs, I prefer to allow the same UI dialog sequence so that they can change the values. 'change' without having to uninstall/reinstall.

Is it supposed to work this way - maybe by how it is scheduled? And if so, is it possible to change that? So far it looks like all of my properties are published in time during a Modify/Change, however the SchedXmlConfig action is confusingly different looking in the logs in a Modify/Change than in an Install

Comment: Could you provide some clarification on: a) What you are seeing in a Modify/Change install, and b) What you want to see in a Modify/Change install?

Comment: Maybe try adding Transitive="yes" in the component, assuming that the UI appears on Modify and sets the desired property.